# remote desktop access

Tags: remote-access, remote-connection

I have my work system on the ip range 172.16.xx.yy, and I have my personal system on the ip range 172.16.aa.bb. Both of them, however, are on the same network of my University, but on different LANs/VLANs (i hope i used the right word here).

How can I remotely connect to my work system from my PC, given that both use private IP addresses?

If such a thing is not possible with current set up, what minimal changes are required for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a static route to 172.16.xx.yy on the router of the 172.16.aa.bb subnet. This router should be connected to 172.16.xx.yy subnet and you define its IP on 172.16.xx.yy as the gateway.

Comment: is your solution feasible in a situation where my personal system is configured for dynamic IP?

Comment: Yes if the main subnet 176.16.xx.yy is not changed (and I don't believe it changes). Even if you personal subnet changes, it should work as the route only needs the main subnet IP. (obs: the reverse route (from the main network to your machine) couldn't be as easily configured with your IP dynamic but this is not what you want anyway).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to the routers then you will need to use an application like [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com). You would need the full version on the personal computer and the unattended host application on your work computer. It is free for personal usage.

Comment: If you want to go from France to Germany, would you go through China? + Let's all give free data statistics to the TeamViewer team.

Comment: This is not a home network. This is at a university, do you think he has access and control of the routers/firewall? Maybe the network admin is his best friend... otherwise what choice does he have?

Comment: You got a point there. :) But he said his 'work system,' so if he works at the university, then it might have the right for suck a routing entry. On the other hand, if he's a student, why would he want remote desktop access to his "work" system, other than being helped remotely? >:)

Comment: @Radoo & Logman-  eh...the network admin's assistant does happen to be my friend. But he says that the only way he knows how to do this is to create a separate VLAN for these two systems of mine. I am looking for a solution involving lesser hassles with the authorities. And of course, Teamviewer is a good application but it won't let me utilize the high speed LAN available to me.

Comment: same ip range now... didnt see the change until after this post

Comment: dynamic IPs, you know... :)

Comment: Dynamic ip range that cross IP classes? odd